# Does this query working like cross join?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run this query but couldn't understand its working process.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T3 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

table1 contains 3 records with sequential id 1, 2, 3 and table2 contains 4 records with sequential id 1, 2, 3, 4 
and one another thing i also want to know that is, does this query executing from right to left? i mean left join process executes first then inner join? i am saying this according to query execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t3
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

The first join is just a normal inner join between `table1` and `table2`.  The second join is a left join, but the `ON` condition is superfluous, and I believe the behavior would be the same without this condition even being there.  The reason for this is that the join condition `t1.id = t2.id` will already always be true at that point in the query, for *every* record in the intermediate table.  Hence, it appears that the second join would effectively be a **cross join** with `table1`.

Typically, your join condition will involve the two tables being joined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's working like a cross join. If this is the intention you should rewrite it correctly. What you have there is misleading and confusing (where did it come from originally?)

```
 select * from table1 t1 
 inner join table2 t2 
 on t1.id=t2.id 
 cross join table1 t3
```

The order that tables, filters, joins are evalulated are dictated by the query plan (press CTRL-L). This may change at any time. You shouldn't be concerned about the ordered these run in - you just need to know that you will get the same results no matter how it is executed. The query planner might choose one method over the other if it thinks it will be faster